# Cluster method that also returns the significance of each feature for clustering?

Tags: clustering, feature-selection

Is there a clustering method that returns the importance of different features for differentiating the clusters, along with the cluster assignments?

Kind of like how post-hoc analysis of decision tree rules helps identify features important to identify classified categories.

Comment: After _any_ clustering method you can undertake to check which of the features used differentiate more and which less, between the clusters. Use any appropriate analysis giving an effect size mesure. Eta for continuous features, phi for categorrical features. One of "internal clustering criterions", Ratkowsky–Lance, is actually that, so when computed for each feature independendently it measures the discriminating importance of the feature.

Comment: In a similar vein, you could re-run your clustering without a variable and measure the similarity to the clustering with all variables, for example using the Adjusted Rand Index. A variable that if left out produces a very different clustering is very influential for the full clustering.

Comment: By the way, I'd advise against picking a clustering method *just because* it delivers this kind of output, because the choice of a good clustering method is very dependent on what kind of clusters you need, what they are used for, what the data are etc. It isn't very sensible to choose a potentially otherwise inappropriate method just because it has an in-built assessment of variable importance, given that you can assess variable importance for any clustering method with the mentioned techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Subspace clustering algorithms.

They will tell you which features are important for a cluster, and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

Here I see a confusuion between supervised/unsupervised approaches. Decision tree is able to rank features because it is supervised and a "good" lerning can be defined. So you can measure how much each feature contributed to this goodness. But what is a "good" clustering? If you can answer tbis you might be able to rank features but there is no answer for this question.

All what you can do is to "define" a measure of goodness for yourself and rank features based on them.

For example, get the projection of data on each feature (axis) and calculate $\frac{BCV}{WCV}$ for each feature, where BCV is between cluster variation (e.g. distance between cluster centroids) and WCV is whithin cluster variation (e.g. inside cluster variance). Larger this score is, more that feature contributed to the clustering.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [finite mixture models with shrinkage on the component means](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-014-9500-2). The very purpose of this modeling approach is to identify which features are relevant when it comes to clustering. You can also find accompanying code online.